# Passing array from PHP to jQuery in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, wordpress

I have been struggling with this for a while. There are tons of topics on the subject but none is actually working for me, but being a newbie might be the cause so please elaborate.

I simplified the code and it won't work, I posted the code below

I am queering the Database, and saving the values to an array in a function
I then need to pass that array to a jquery in the same function. I used json_encode but i am getting this error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Here is the code:

```
function Test()
{
    $query1 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT(element_value) FROM wp_piic_formmaker_submits WHERE form_id = 13 AND  element_label = 1 AND user_id_wd = 1 ORDER BY date asc", OBJECT);

    if($query1)
    {
        foreach($query1 as $q)
        {
            $PHPArray[$i] = $q->element_value ;
            $i = $i + 1;
        }
    }

    $UserInput = "<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery('#wdform_1_element13').on('change',function()
    {   
        var test = <?php echo json_encode($PHPArray); ?>;
        jQuery.each(test , function (i, elem)
        {
            alert('here');
        });
    }); 
    </script>";

    return $UserInput ;
}
```

Comment: Try to call your function from ajax ..then you can get response of json_encode into java script function.

Comment: Sometimes cut&paste is not enough eh?! :) Just change to this `var test = ".json_encode($PHPArray).";`

Comment: That worked Yuri! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
$UserInput = "<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery('#wdform_1_element13').on('change',function()
{   
    var test = ".json_encode($PHPArray)."; //Notice the change here
    jQuery.each(test , function (i, elem)
    {
        alert('here');
    });
}); 
</script>";

return $UserInput ;
```

}

Comment: No, I was not. You can use a JSON encoded array directly in JS. There is no need für the quotes. I was reading the code wrong. My fault. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the string correctly:

```
function Test()
{
    $query1 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT(element_value) FROM wp_piic_formmaker_submits WHERE form_id = 13 AND  element_label = 1 AND user_id_wd = 1 ORDER BY date asc", OBJECT);

    if($query1)
    {
        foreach($query1 as $q)
        {
            $PHPArray[$i] = $q->element_value ;
            $i = $i + 1;
        }
    }

    $UserInput = "<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery('#wdform_1_element13').on('change',function()
    {   
        var test = " . json_encode($PHPArray) . ";
        jQuery.each(test , function (i, elem)
        {
            alert('here');
        });
    }); 
    </script>";

    return $UserInput ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put PHP inside JavaScript  the PHP part is only text, do this:

```
function Test()
{
    $query1 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT(element_value) FROM wp_piic_formmaker_submits WHERE form_id = 13 AND  element_label = 1 AND user_id_wd = 1 ORDER BY date asc", OBJECT);

    if($query1)
    {
        foreach($query1 as $q)
        {
            $PHPArray[$i] = $q->element_value ;
            $i = $i + 1;
        }
    }

    $UserInput = "<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery('#wdform_1_element13').on('change',function()
    {   
        var test = " . json_encode($PHPArray) . ";
        jQuery.each(test , function (i, elem)
        {
            alert('here');
        });
    }); 
    </script>";

    return $UserInput ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At least from what is shown, neither `$i` nor `$PHPArray` are initialized. PHP can be messy about these things, but you cannot directly refer to indexes of non-existent arrays, or variables that have not been declared.

I'll guess the token error was from your browser trying to deal with the text output of a PHP error being flushed, along the lines of 'undefiend' or 'undefined index.'

Also, the real (or at least convenient) purpose of the foreach construct is not fooling with indexes. Try the following substitute for your current loop:

```
$PHPArray = array(); // $PHPArray = [];
if($query1){    
    foreach($query1 as $q){
       $PHPArray[] = $q->element_value;
    }
}
```

Beyond that, "wpdb" suggests calls related to specific frameworks, but in case this is a mysqli_stmt call, i believe the call is singular: `get_result`.

Comment: That's a good lesson learned! the code others posted worked but I made sure to initialize the my variables too! thanks